# REST API Create Session Error [tokbox] or [opentok]

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Getting an issue when trying to call opentok/session/create api. 
When calling the api through code i keep getting an error saying the connection has been closed. So I decided to try through postman and the error i'm getting back is a 500 internal server error and a message

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error, working hard to fix it, sorry",
    "code": -1
}
```

As far as I can see I have everything set correctly.
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3CXI.png), [Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgMuJ.png) ]

I don't think this is a JWT issue as according to the documentation that would be a 403. https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#session_id_production

Anyone experienced this or a similar issue before

Comment: Try removing the `Content-Type` header from the request.  I've seen this cause issues with requests to OpenTok `v1` API endpoints.

Comment: @adrice727 This wasn't the exact answer but it set me on the right track. I had to specifically set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being the content Content-Type header I had to set

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Credit to @adrice727's comment for suggesting there might be an issue with the Content-Type header.

Comment: This worked for me as well, despite not being anywhere in their API documentation. Thanks a lot!